# How test function in SQL Plus

Tags: sqlplus

How I can test this function in SQL Plus?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validid(
    p_deptid IN dept.deptno%TYPE
)
RETURN BOOLEAN IS
    v_dummy PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT 1
    INTO v_dummy
    FROM dept
    WHERE deptno = p_deptid;

    RETURN TRUE;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            RETURN FALSE;
END validid;
/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the function returns Boolean, you can't test it by calling it from SQL. You need to call it from PL/SQL. Below I show a small anonymous block that calls the function and outputs something to the screen. To see the results, you may have to execute the command `set serveroutput on` first. (It's a SQL*Plus command, not SQL or PL/SQL, so you don't need to end it with semicolon or slash.)

Of course, I assume the function compiles correctly - which means you do have a table DEPT in your schema, and that it has a column DEPTNO. Otherwise you would get a compilation error.

```
set serveroutput on

begin
  if validid(20) 
    then dbms_output.put_line('20 is valid');
    else dbms_output.put_line('20 is invalid');
  end if;
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

20 is valid
```